# Extras on demand in a Android Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

In one of the activities of my application the user can select the language. Since the app is only in 5 languages I'd like to do something like:

When the user press the button language show a dialog displaying the 5 main languages, and a extra option:"Show more languages". If the user select the last one then show the complete list.

I really dont know how to implement that keeping the action natural for the user, since reloading the dialog with all the languages can be confusing.

How can I make that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how it is done in the Settings->Language&Keyboard->Select Language it might give you the right idea. Otherwise you can use context menus and sub-menus with lists to implement it.
Remember that activities have to be restarted in order to apply the language.

---

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

i think you could list all languages in a linearlayout surrounded by a scrollview, all hided and added to dialog. When user click button `show more languages` you could show the layout hided :)